# Efficient lookup from pyspark in cosmosdb

Tags: pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

In a spark job I need to retrieve data from cosmosdb on ~ 20000 documents whose ids and partitionkey I know.

My current code, which is awfully slow, is to prepare a query `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.pkey = %{pkey}i AND c.id in (%{ids}s)` and I have a loop to sequentially query cosmosdb injecting in this query a batch of ~500 up to 1000 ids from the same partition. (Then using a union to assemble the dataframe)

Each of those queries is taking between 30s and a minute. It would be so much faster in SQLServer I don't understand what's going on. (I should add that those queries max out the 50k RUs capacity of the collection (or container as they are now called) which is quite surprising)

How could I do this more efficiently ?

edit : code sample

```
for pil in partitionedIdsLists :
  for idsList in pil[1] :
    idsEtabsString = r'"'+r'","'.join(idsList)+r'"'
    part_df = spark\
                .read\
                .schema(schema_df)\
                .format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark")\
                .options(
                  **readConfigET, 
                  query_custom = r'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c["pkey"] = %(pkey)i AND c["id"] in (%(listeIds)s)'%{'pkey' : pil[0], 'listeIds' : idsEtabsString}
                )\
                .load()\
                .distinct()

    if full_df is None :
      full_df = spark\
                  .createDataFrame([], schema_df)

    full_df = full_df\
                .union(part_df)
```

partitionedIdsLists being a list of couples `(pkey,[[id1,..,id500],[id501,..,id1000]])`

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code? Which connector are you using?

Comment: @simon_dmorias 

edited with a code sample, 
the connector is azure_cosmosdb_spark 2.4.0 2.11

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure you have the latest version: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11/1.3.5/jar - anything prior to version 1.2.2 has awful performance.

You should not have to loop on each partition - a single read (which will scale out on your workers) will be the most efficient. Spark should create a job per cosmosdb partition - but you have manually calculated that and are now running them serially, which will consume only one core on your cluster at a time. If you have a lot of partitions this will be terrible performance.

If your list of ID's is long (thousands+) then I can see this also being an issue. Assuming you have no other way of selecting them I would write them to cosmosdb with the same partition key first - then join in your sql query. Assuming you align the partitions this should be very efficient.

I can't see you readConfigET. But play with different page sizes: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/wiki/Configuration-references
Also why is the distinct there? If you have id in the select list it should not be possible to get duplicates? Have you tested without the distinct?

Comment: I'm on the latest version yes.
I added the partition key this morning, it's indeed slower than my attempts yesterday without it, I will reverse this. (and remove the distinct)

I will  try to change the pageSize and get back to you.

Comment: pagesize will have minimal effect to be honest. How many items are in these lists?

Comment: Oh you said 500-1000. That's quite a lot - I would write them first, with the partition, and then join to them.

Comment: Yes, between 20k and 30k docs each day. I split them to avoid the string of the sqlquery to be too long to handle for the connector (I've had this issue in the past.)

'm not sure I understand what you mean by writing then joining. Would that be cosmosdb-side or spark-side ?

Comment: Try both. Put the list of ids into a dataframe with the partitionid and write that dataframe to another collection in cosmosdb. Then join on both columns in the select. Alternatively, instead of writing it to cosmosdb you could broadcast it and then join it in spark.

Comment: I was under the impression that cross-document and cross-collections joins were not supported by cosmosdb...

Comment: Yeah sorry you are right. The pyspark join should still be better though. I will update my answer with some sample code later this afternoon